# ZF2 TableGateway join

Tags: zend-framework2

I am in the process of trying to learn OO/Zend Framework over standard PHP.. I want to scream and write a mysql query instead of using the TableGateway method.

I have been following tutorials and have successfully printed out a table and some fields, although with the way I have gone about doing this, I am totally lost in how I should make this a join with another table and print out some fields there.

For example.

Table       Fields
customer    Idx, Company
contact     Idx, First_Name

This is my customersController where I assume the work is carried out

```
      namespace Customers\Controller;

      use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
      use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
      use Zend\DB\TableGateway\TableGateway;


class CustomersController extends AbstractActionController
 {

 protected $customersTable;

 public function indexAction()
 {
     return new ViewModel(array('customer' => $this->getCustomersTable()->select()));
     //return new ViewModel(array('customers' => $this->fetchJoin()->select()));
 }

 public function addAction()
 {
 }

 public function editAction()
 {
 }

 public function deleteAction()
 {
 }

 public function getCustomersTable()
 {
        if (!$this->customersTable) {
        $this->customersTable = new TableGateway (
        'customer', //table name
         $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\DB\Adapter\Adapter')
         );
     }
     return $this->customersTable;


    }

   }
```

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make joins read about Zend\Db\Sql and Zend\Db\Select
which you can read about here

> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html

An example would be:

In your model(that extends the TableGateway or the AbstractTableGateway) 
in Some function you can have something like(this is from a project) :

```
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($this->getAdapter());

$select = $sql->select()
    ->from('event_related_events')
    ->columns(array())
    ->join('event_invitees', 'event_invitees.event_id = 
       event_related_events.related_event_id')
    ->where(array('event_related_events.event_id' => $eventId));

$selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select); 
$results      = $this->getAdapter()->query($selectString, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

Then you can loop over the results and do what you need to.

Taking a look at more powerful ORM like Doctrine or Propel may also help, but may be an overkill for a small/hobby project.

---

EDIT: Answer for what was asked in comments

For Using expression(if, case etc) directly you can use something like :

```
 $sql->select()
    ->from('table')
    ->columns(array(
        'sorter' => new Expression('(IF ( table.`something` >= 'otherthing',  1,  0))'),
    'some_count' => new Expression('(count(*))'),
    )
)
```

Explaining the last line in SQL terms, it would be: 
count(*) AS some_count

Comment: Nice example. I do not agree with your statement about doctrine and propel though. I tend to use an ORM in "small" projects, and fall back to Zend components when the application is too complex to rely on the ORM alone. Don't get me wrong, I like doctrine very much. I don't like propel but I do use it when I have to. I'm not taking the overhead into here. I feel like using an ORM in applications that frequently change and require alot of flexibility in the model often leads to poor design choices to make something 'work'.  An ORM is designed to work with implementations rather than interfaces.

Comment: But than again. In most cases, doctrine has all the features you'll need. I would say choose the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my controller, basically from the Album example but now it will display customers from the customer table.

```
<?php

    namespace Customers\Controller;

     use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
     use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
     use Customers\Model\Customers;          
     use Customers\Form\CustomersForm; 

     class CustomersController extends AbstractActionController
     {

      protected $customersTable;

         public function indexAction()
         {
             return new ViewModel(array(
                 'customer' => $this->getCustomersTable()->fetchAll(),
             ));
         }

        public function addAction()
        {
        }

        public function editAction()
         {
         }

        public function deleteAction()
        {
        }

         public function getCustomersTable()
         {
             if (!$this->customersTable) {
                 $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
                 $this->customersTable = $sm->get('Customers\Model\CustomersTable');
             }
             return $this->customersTable;
         }



     }


     ?>
```

The indexAction calls the getCustomersTable method which goes to the model (CustomersTable) and executes the "query" there.

```
<?php

namespace Customers\Model;

 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

 class CustomersTable
 {
     protected $tableGateway;

     public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
     {
         $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
     }

     public function fetchAll()
     {
         $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
         return $resultSet;
     }

     public function getCustomers($id)
     {

     }

     public function saveCustomers(customers $customers)
     {

     }


     public function deleteCustomers($id)
     {
     }
 }

 ?>
```

So from your example, I should be trying to implement this into the fetchAll in the model?
Thanks for the help.

```
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($this->getAdapter());

        $select = $sql->select()
    ->from('customer')
    ->columns(array())
    ->join('contact', 'contact.Idx = customer.Idx')
    ->where(array('contact.Idx' => $eventId));

$selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select); 
$results      = $this->getAdapter()->query($selectString, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

Comment: Yes you can do that, depends on you though, but as you are getting Contacts for a customer, then having a function named getContacts() or something like that, would be better.

Comment: Oh great, I got this working.  Thanks alot.  Although to take this a step further, in my sql query I have some conditions, for example.

select location.* 
if ( xxxxxxx ) as Name
where ....

Is this possible to do with tablegateway?

Comment: Have a look at Zend\Db\Sql\Expression, maybe that is what you need.

Comment: Adding an example for you in the answer