# Zend Framework 2 Query

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

How can customised my query.. this is my current code in my controller:

```
class PostController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $userTable;

    // CRUD
    // retrieve
    public function indexAction(){
        return new ViewModel(
                array(
                    'rowset'    => $this->getPostsTable()->select(),
                )
            );
    }
    public function getPostsTable(){
        if(!$this->userTable){
            $this->userTable = new TableGateway(
                    'posts',
                    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
                );
        }

        return $this->userTable;
    }

}
```

How can i order the result to descending?
And how to join another table with that code?

Comment: Please take a look at this question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024047/zf2-tablegateway-join and read the documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Zend framework is an MVC Framework.

Means that your Data Object Access MUST be in Model layer NOT IN Controller.

Your PostController can't have Model logic in it, it's bad. And it may be throw so much error that you will not understand directly.

Plus, call getServiceLocator in Controller is a bad practise and it will be removes in Zf3. That's why using Model Layer is recommanded.

For your problem, you have to make a query builder like this :

```
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($this->getAdapter());

$select = $sql->select()
    ->from('tableName')
    ->columns(array())
    ->join('tableName2', 'Your ON Clause')
    ->where(array('if you Have WhereClause'))
    ->order('Your column DESC');
```

I use Doctrine but i'm pretty sure (community will confirm this or not) this example may work.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for you answer, it's been a very big help :)